# Trying to understand ruby syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a new to ruby and i dont understand some example

can anybody explain this expession

```
redirect_to @message ? read_account_inbox_message_url(@message) : account_inbox_url
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `@message` return `true` then redirect to `read_account_inbox_message_url(@message)` url, else redirect to `account_inbox_url`

[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a#Ruby)

Comment: It is a shorthand if statement

Comment: The `@message` doesn't need to be `true`, it only needs to be "truthy" (i.e. not `nil` and not `false`)

Answer (score 2):

It's called the ternary operator. And it's the shorthand for

```
redirect_to if @message
  read_account_inbox_message_url(@message)
else
  account_inbox_url
end
```

As an if statement it checks for the condition truthfulness and returns the evaluation of the first part or else the second part.

Answer (score 1):

It's called the ternary operator. It's shorthand for saying:

```
if redirect_to @message is true 
  then
read_account_inbox_message_url(@message)
  otherwise 
account_inbox_url
```

The syntax is

```
test ? if_test_result_is_true_then_do_this : if_test_result_is_false_then_do_this
```

Answer (score 1):

It is the same:

```
if @message
  read_account_inbox_message_url(@message)
else
  account_inbox_url
end
```

Answer (score 1):

[`?:`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a) is a ternary conditional expression:

```
condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false
```

It's a shorthand for:

```
if condition
  value_if_true
else
  value_if_false
end
```

In your example, `@message` is the condition, `read_account_inbox_message_url(@message)` is the "true-value" and `account_inbox_url` is the "false-value". After evaluation, `redirect_to` is called with the expression's result.

It's equivalent to (and I would write it this way):

```
if @message
  redirect_to read_account_inbox_message_url(@message)
else
  redirect_to account_inbox_url
end
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a ternary expression used as an argument to the method [`redirect_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to).

In words, it means: `redirect to read_account_inbox_message_url(@message) if @message is true, or, redirect_to account_inbox_url`

The format of a ternary expression is: `expression ? evaluate_if_true : evaluate_if_false`.

Answer (score 0):

This code is eqivalent to:

```
redirect_to (@message ? read_account_inbox_message_url(@message) : account_inbox_url)
```

If `@message` is "truthy" (in Ruby, everything except `nil` and `false` is truthy), the result of `read_account_inbox_message_url(@message)` will be passed as argument to `redirect_to` method. Otherwise `account_inbox_url` result will be passed.